# Why does TIMESTAMPDIFF always return null?

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to inform the user that there is maintenance being performed on the server and provide them with the remaining time until the maintenance is complete. However, I encountered a problem with the MySQL query.

**Here is the query that I used:**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), STR_TO_DATE(JSON_EXTRACT(VALUE_, '$.END_DATE'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) AS SECONDS_LEFT FROM SETTINGS WHERE KEY_ = 'MAINTENANCE'
```

Unfortunately, the query always returns a null value.

Please find below the table structure and data for your reference.

```
CREATE TABLE `settings` (
  `KEY_` char(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `VALUE_` json NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `KEY_` (`KEY_`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

| KEY_ | VALUE_ |
| --- | --- |
| MAINTENANCE | { "END_DATE": "2021-01-07 23:46:53" } |

Could you please assist me in identifying what I may have missed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this... `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), STR_TO_DATE(JSON_EXTRACT(VALUE_, '$.END_DATE'), '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"')) AS SECONDS_LEFT FROM SETTINGS WHERE KEY_ = 'MAINTENANCE'`.
The reason is, `JSON_EXTRACT(VALUE_, '$.END_DATE')` returns `"2021-01-07 23:46:53"` (with double quotes)

Comment: I just changed `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'` in your query to `'"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"'` - i.e. added double-quotes in the formatting.  And now I get the result as `-72373427`.

Comment: @Ishan I discovered the solution at the same time you commented. You are correct. For me I used `JSON_UNQUOTE`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make a _column_ for `end_date` rather than heading it inside a JSON string?

Comment: @RickJames The settings table is designed for admin panel settings. However, since MySQL doesn't support multiple datatypes for the same column, I believe that using JSON would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), STR_TO_DATE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(VALUE_, '$.END_DATE')), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) AS SECONDS_LEFT FROM SETTINGS WHERE KEY_ = 'MAINTENANCE';
```